# Non-yielding issue on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

We currently have an issue with some queries/jobs causing non-yielding at a specific point in time.

There no are mini dumps which are generated when this happens.

Is there a way to know which query was causing the non-yielding on a specific scheduler in the past?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your Wait Stats (preferably Query Store Wait Stats, Session Wait Stats, and otherwise System Wait Stats) for preemptive waits.

Sessions enter preemptive waits when calling into code that doesn't participate with SQL Server's cooperative scheduler, which is a common cause of a session refusing to yield a scheduler (CPU Core).